# Where do I store my tokens server side?

Tags: php, authentication, extjs

I made (myself) an authentication system for my ExtJS app.

When I login my server generates a token which is stored by my client. When I have to send a request to my server I put my token in the request headers, but what is the common way to check the token server side?

Do I have to store the token in my database, do a select query, etc.?

Does it in another way? Querying my database 1 more time for each request doesn't seems a good idea for me (but maybe I'm wrong)

Comment: I've used JWT which generates the tokens and passes them to the client, and then validates them when passed back from the client, perhaps worth having a look how that works.

Comment: i would like to do it myself it's for education purpose @NigelRen

Comment: It is still useful to understand how it works as you can see what other systems do.

Comment: @NigelRen how it works is exactly what I ask here. I just ask a simple explaination from someone who knows the topic. I know jwt, never used it but already read about it and know it exists. I want an explaination of where my token is stored server-side, if i have to request my db just for tokens handling etc.

Comment: This should answer your question - [Stateless Sessions for Stateful Minds](https://auth0.com/blog/stateless-auth-for-stateful-minds/)!

Comment: JWT tokens aren't stored server side, the server just checks it is valid when passed back.

Comment: @NigelRen and what is the process to check if it's valid ? does the server have a master key and check if the token has be encoded using it ? something else ?

Comment: @NigelRen JWT might be stored in the database in case you want to set up a revoking step (like facebook when you want to "kill" all the others actives sessions), thus forcing your script to loop through revoked tokens attached to the user record, and check if the received token in the header is not blacklisted, if yes, sending him back a 403 (forbidden), or the Microsoft's 440 (login timed out)